# Can we emulate Kindles?

Tags: android-emulator, amazon-kindle

There are emulators which run on Kindles but I can't seem to find an emulator which runs on a computer and emulates a Kindle device. Closest I can find is for authors checking page formats.

I know Kindles run Android, but there are definitely differences in the OS. I'd like to emulate the full environment, everything from using Amazon Coins as a payment method to cross-app interaction and functionality.

**Are there Kindle emulators, and if so why is Kindle not included alongside other Android versions in most emulators (like MEmu, etc)? If not, why not?**

Note: I don't want this to be a "shopping" question. I don't care about the relative merits of different emulators, if any. A list of emulators would be useful, but I really want to know why emulating Kindle OS isn't a standard feature in existing emulators.

Comment: Fire OS is closed source - most manufacturer's UI/UX are.

Comment: @AndyYan So is Windows, OS X, etc, but I can do virtual machines, emulators, and similar things for them (WINE, CrossOver, VMWare, etc). Should I be looking for a VM of Fire OS instead of emulation?

Comment: @Taejang Windows and OSX provides unified binaries (.iso files or something else) that can run on ANY x86/amd64 architecture. A VM can emulate x86 or amd64 architecture quite nicely, hence they run fine on VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why emulating Kindle OS isn't a standard feature in existing emulators

Android isn't like Windows. Sure it runs on billions of devices just like Windows but there is no one single unified OS binary for Android that runs across multiple SoCs. Each Android device needs a lot of closed source blobs from the SoC manufacturer, starting from boot to every single driver.

There is nothing available openly to make Fire OS run on hardware other than a Kindle. No source for the OS. No drivers. No unified binary blob that runs on architecture that a VM emulates.